# how to link/add xml url in the xsl file

Tags: xslt

i have a xsl file as below:

```
-------Begin------
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Content Cert the following App Images</h1>

    <h3>APPX Images</h3>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="rgb(0,176,240)">
        <th>Images</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Images/Image">
         <tr>
           <td>
             <img>
               <xsl:attribute name="src">
                 <xsl:value-of select="ImageURL"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
             </img>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </table>


    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
--------end--------
```

i have a xml file in my local path. using this xsl file i am creating an mht file which will display the Image as i eneterd in the xsl file

Now i am trying to link the xml file which is already present in my loacl path in the xsl file. i have tried using the `<a href = "c:\data\test.xml"></a>`

i donn't see the xml link is getting embeded in the mht file. could you please help in this how to link /add the xml url in the xsl file and where should i add that line of code?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to `body` element this node:

```
<a href="c:\data\test.xml">Link to XML</a>
```

Comment: This works perfect. If i want to display the whole XML content at the end of the file rather than giving a link, could you please let me know what is the change i should do in the above instruction?

Comment: I have tried with the below command <xsl:import href = "c:\image\test.xml"> <xsl:apply-imports/> but it doesn't display with the actual data what i expected. how to display the exact info what we see when we open an xml file?